# Grep Regex to select last word including escaped spaces

Tags: regex, grep

I have the following grep command, which selects the last word of an outputted line.:

```
grep -o "[^ ]*$"
```

I am using this to select paths to filenames that are outputted by a program as the last word of the line like this:

```
~some stuff~ path
```

my issue is that if the path has escaped spaces "`Some\ Word`", then the regex will obviously only select "Word".  Is there a way I can have it select spaces, but not escaped spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this would work for you:

```
grep -Eo '([^ ]|\\ )*$'
```

for example:

```
kent$  cat file
foo some\ word1
foo this word2
foo the\ whole\ word

kent$  grep -Eo '([^ ]|\\ )*$' file                                                                                                                                         
some\ word1
word2
the\ whole\ word
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a positive lookbehind:

```
((?<=\\) |[^ ])+$
```

Comment: My first thought too. But this would then require `GNU grep`, with the `-P` flag.